# Command after apt-get install is not executing in script

Tags: apt, bash, scripts, ssh

I wrote a [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/769488/command-after-apt-get-install-is-not-executing-in-script) on Server Fault, but I guess it's more applicable for this community.

I'm writing a script which is meant to initially set up my Droplet. In the script, I'm opening SSH connection with my Ubuntu 14.04 server as follows (with `USER` and `REMOTE` variables previously defined):

```
ssh -t -t $USER@$REMOTE <<'ENDSSH'
ENDSSH
```

Inside of that SSH connection, I have multiple commands which I want to execute - installing Node.js, updating npm, installing MongoDB and so on.

But, once I do a `apt-get install` command, other commands do not get executed.

So, if I have this:

```
ssh -t -t $USER@$REMOTE <<'ENDSSH'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install -y npm
ENDSSH
```

Command `sudo apt-get install -y npm` won't be executed. Now, I know that I can install multiple packages within the same `apt-get install` command, but this is not what I'm asking, since other commands afterwards won't get executed than. This example I just wrote out of simplicity so I can explain my problem. Concretely, I have these commands:

```
ssh -tt $USER@$REMOTE <<'ENDSSH'
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo npm install -g npm
ENDSSH
```

Command `sudo npm install -g npm` and everything following it never gets executed.

I came across questions like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/489939/ssh-session-never-closes-when-executing-apt-get-install) where they say I should put multiple `-t` flags (or `-tt`) when opening `ssh` connection, which I'm doing, but that doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have configured `sudoers` to run without password?

Comment: Yes, I do have it configured.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182625/70524?

Comment: You don't need single quotes in ENDSSH

Answer (score 1):

You might want to end your lines with `&&` so the script only advances when the command is done. Example:

```
ssh -t -t $USER@$REMOTE <<'ENDSSH'
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs &&
sudo apt-get install -y npm
ENDSSH
```